# List out all SVN repos created by various users in their own locations

Tags: list, svn, svnadmin

How do I list all the subversion repos created with `svnadmin create` by various users?
I want to setup a method to backup the repositories.
But first, I should know a list of them.
Many users might have created their own repos into multiple locations.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to scan for the SVN repository folders. If you find a folder containing the following items it is safe to say you found an svn repo:

- folder conf
- folder db
- folder hooks
- folder locks
- file fs-type

Answer (score 0):

This Is when I start wondering if you really want to do this.

perhaps a more centralised repo would be a better idea? or if you have a distributed model, use something like git or hg.